# How do I filter returned resource groups by role definitions?

Tags: azure, azure-management-api, azure-rest-api

I'm trying to make a GET request to list all of the available resource groups by the authenticated user's Role Assignment; in this case, "contributor".

I've looked at [listing role assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments/list) but I can't seem to use "contributor" as a filter when requesting a [list of resource groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resourcegroups/list).

```sh
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups?$filter={$filter}&api-version=2019-05-10
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no way to filter resource group by role assignment.

You could go to [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management) to give you feedback.